# How to find out which method an API call is hitting in my MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, api

I inherited an MVC application and I can normally deduce where an API call hits but this time I'm stumped. API call info:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3100/api/account 
Request Method: GET 
Status Code: 200 OK
```

RouteConfig looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Global.asax has:

```
private const string _WebApiPrefix = "api";
private static string _WebApiExecutionPath = String.Format("~/{0}", _WebApiPrefix);

private static bool IsWebApiRequest()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith(_WebApiExecutionPath);
}
```

And I'm not really sure where else to look. There is no AccountController that I can find. Is there some way that I can find the controller entry point into the application for this call?

Answer (score 0):

Create an action filter to all controllers.

```
public class LogFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
      public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
      {
         Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Action {0} on Controller {1}", actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName, actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName));
      }
}
```

on global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new LogFilter());
}
```

Just check the console after typing "http://localhost:3100/api/account". It will log the action and the controller. Or place a breakpoint in OnActionExecuting method, the next method executed will be he method that you are searching for.